# python return variable value when combine strings

Tags: python

```
men_apparel = ['shirts','jeans','trousers', 'jackets']
women_apparel = ['kurtas','jeans', 'sarees', 'tshirts']
men_footware = ['sneakers','running', 'flats', 'sports']
women_footware = ['heels','flats','casual']


gender = input("Enter gender: ")
category = input("Enter category: ")

print("Your search results are: {}_{}".format(gender,category))
```

**Execution:**

```
Enter gender: male
Enter category: apparel
```

**Actual Result :**

```
Your search results are : male_apparel
```

**Expected Result**

```
Your search results are: ['shirts','jeans','trousers', 'jackets']
```

similarly any such combination of user inputs should return the declared variable rather than actual string

Comment: Put the lists into a `dict` and use the key as the lookup.  What have you researched/tried so far?

Comment: Read about `if` statement. Or read about `dict`s.

Comment: @S3DEV: stored both user inputs as res = gender+'_'+category and print res, even that gives the same result as earlier..let me try with dict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just now printing what the user entered. You should be looking into creating a dictionary with the names (e.g. 'men_apparel') as key, and as values the list of clothing types.

```
items = {
  'men_apparel': ['shirts','jeans','trousers', 'jackets'],
  'women_apparel': ['kurtas','jeans', 'sarees', 'tshirts'],
  'men_footware': ['sneakers','running', 'flats', 'sports'],
  'women_footware': ['heels','flats','casual'],
}

gender = input("Enter gender: ")
category = input("Enter category: ")

item_name = f"{gender}_{category}"


print(f"Your search results are: {items[item_name]}")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
clothes = {'man_apparel': ['shirts','jeans','trousers', 'jackets'],
'women_apparel':['kurtas','jeans', 'sarees', 'tshirts'],
'men_footware':['sneakers','running', 'flats', 'sports'],
'women_footware':['heels','flats','casual']}

gender = input("Enter gender: ")
category = input("Enter category: ")
a = '{}_{}'.format(gender, category)

print("Your search results are:", clothes[a])
```